# Can InetAddress represent host names that can't be resolved?

Tags: java, networking

I parse various data sources with network information in them.

I have been using [java.net.InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) to represent and parse hosts. It works fine being initialized with IP.

I have to parse a new source now. It contains hostnames instead of IP's. [InetAddress.getByName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) throws UnknownHostException if a hostname argument can't be resolved to an IP. Host IP isn't absolutely neccessary for my goal. Dropping the data just because of DNS failure is unacceptable for me.

I'd like to have an IP address if it is obtainable or a hostname otherwise.

How do I prevent resolve of given hostnames? Is there another class that is more suited for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is not possible, because the core function of InetAddress is to handle IP-Addresses:

> This class represents an Internet
>   Protocol (IP) address.
>
> An IP address is either a 32-bit or
>   128-bit unsigned number used by IP, a
>   lower-level protocol on which
>   protocols like UDP and TCP are built.
>   The IP address architecture is defined
>   by RFC 790: Assigned Numbers, RFC
>   1918: Address Allocation for Private
>   Internets, RFC 2365: Administratively
>   Scoped IP Multicast, and RFC 2373: IP
>   Version 6 Addressing Architecture. An
>   instance of an InetAddress consists of
>   an IP address and possibly its
>   corresponding host name (depending on
>   whether it is constructed with a host
>   name or whether it has already done
>   reverse host name resolution).

You have no possibility to construct an InetAddress object without an IP-address.

For you purpose you need to define a Hostname.class, which holds the hostname and maybe additional data. This class should/can handle all the domainname internationalization via [IDN](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html), if you are using Java 6. There are separate IDN libraries available if you are on Java 5.

A separate Hostname.class can also define guards or constructors, which assure only valid hostnames according to the relevant RFCs.

Comment: just try to make up a simple program with line `InetAddress.getByName("google.com")` and you'll see that you're wrong here.

Comment: Of course,  because `google.com` has an IP-address. If you want me to prove wrong show me how to get an InetAddress object for an hostname without an existing IP-address from somekind of DNS. This is the all about in this question. And remove your downvote, because you are wrong.

Comment: I think, I get what you and @Basilevs are talking about. And the question seems to me very strange now because there is actually no any difference between simple string and 'inet address' of host without real ip address 'under the hood'.

Comment: @Roman: This is the question: `Can InetAddress represent host names that can't be resolved?`

Comment: @Roman: read the docs - "this class represents an Internet Protocol (IP) address". There are various static helper methods that create InetAddress objects by performing a DNS lookup, but without a matching DNS record an InetAddress cannot be created - in fact, it's meaningless to do so (since there's no IP address to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

The method `InetAddress.getByAddress(String host, byte[] addr)` does not perform a query to the DNS and allows you to create an `InetAddress` having arbitrary hostname and IP address, possibly the IPv4 unspecified address (0.0.0.0).

Try creating the `InetAddress` with `getByName`, if it throws you can create it by using `getByAddress`. Note that you will need to check the IP addresses are valid before actually using them.

---

Example code:

```
  public static void main(String arg[])
    throws  UnknownHostException
  {
    InetAddress a;
    byte[] unspec = new byte[4];
    unspec[0]=0;
    unspec[1]=0;
    unspec[2]=0;
    unspec[3]=0;
    try
    {
      a = InetAddress.getByName(arg[0]);
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
      a = InetAddress.getByAddress(arg[0],unspec);
    }
    System.out.println(a);
  }
```

Comment: This will generate InetAddress objects, where hostname and ip-address will not fit together. Especially `0.0.0.0` is reserved for the `default network`.

Comment: I beleive this answer is the closest to what I need. Unfortunately zeroed IP breaks comparison functionality of InetAddress which is bad for my needs.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for a way to mock InetAddress objects with a 3rd party api.  For my use the api has to use InetAddress, but the name is important but the ipaddress is not.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a new class? It would only need to be able to store a String and an InetAddress.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved Issue by editing `/etc/hosts` file:

I also had similar issue (`InetAddress.getByName` not working with hostname).

I resolved it by removing entries like `::1 localhost`, `ff81::1%lo0 localhost` with only 127.0.0.1 localhost.

I removed rest of the entries for localhost. I did this for my Mac.

*Sometime, what ever information that I given is not working. In that case, I just moved the file /etc/hosts file to hosts_backup. then restored the file. ie moved file hosts_backup to /etc/hosts. then it starts working. Don't know how it is working. But it resolved my issue*

Answer (score -1):

I've just made some experiments with `InetAddress` class and also read its javadocs.

After the first touch I can tell that I get `UnknownHostException` in 2 cases: either when I pass illegal formated string (like `http://stackoverflow.com` instead of `stackoverflow.com`) or when I pass URL that cannot be resolved in browser too (i.e. something like `aosjdfk23423.com`).

Both cases are documented in javadocs (although it's not explicitely said anywhere anything strict about the parameter format). Here are related javadocs parts:

> The host name can either be a machine name, such as
>        `java.sun.com`, or a textual representation of its
>         IP address. If a literal IP address is supplied, only the
>         validity of the address format is checked.

> @exception  UnknownHostException  if no IP address for the
>                 `host` could be found, or if a scope_id was specified
>              for a global IPv6 address.

Summary:

this works:

```
InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
InetAddress.getByName("74.125.87.99");
```

and this throws `UnknownHostException`:

```
InetAddress.getByName("http://google.com");
InetAddress.getByName("unexistingresourse234234.com");
```

UPD (as an answer to the comments: there should be something like this:

```
List<String> hosts = getPossibleHosts(); //these are all hosts you want to transform into inet addresses
final List<InetAddress> inetAddresses = new LinkedList<InetAddress>();
final List<String> badHosts = new LinkedList<String>();

for(String host : hosts) {
    try {
        inetAddresses.add(InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        badHosts.add(host);
    }
}
```

After that you can process both lists as you wish. But it's a mistake to try to put them in the same list - they are not same.

Comment: So it is impossible to make getByName silently accept nonexistent domain, isn't it?

Comment: @Basilevs: welcome to Java World! Use try/catch block. I recommend you to read some manual about exceptions in java.

Comment: Be so kind to show how to use try/catch in this issue, for example for `InetAddress ia=InetAddress.getByName("google.invalid"); System.out.println(ia.getHostname());`

Comment: Well, that's the point. You get no `InetAddress` without an exiting IP-address. But that was the original question, if it is possible to get an InetAddress object without hostname resolution: `Can InetAddress represent host names that can't be resolved?``

Comment: @Michael Konietzka: you could downvote me without asking to add the code snippet.